# How can I display the current url in swagger ui?

Tags: url, swagger, display, hostname, absolute-path

I would like to display the current url, eg.: https://{hostname}/{pathname}..., where I am running the swagger ui on instead of a hardcoded relative path, accordingly. Is there any possible solution to do so at least to get the current hostname? [Like in the screenshot here where the same url is shown in swagger as well as in the adressbar of the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln6a2.png)

I've tried several things but it seemed that text in swagger can only be hard coded.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: Hy Helen,  thank you for the hint. Just added a screenshot.

Comment: Your screenshot shows absolute URLs. Where are the relative URLs that you want to change to absolute URLs?

Comment: Unfortunetly, I can't show my application because it contains some confidential information. In my application I only have relativ urls e.g. ./somepath/example.json which I want to change to absolute-paths like here [example_link](http://petstore.swagger.io/?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/master/examples/v2.0/json/api-with-examples.json#/default/getVersionDetailsv2) For instance, the path below the header in this example is refering to the json file with an absolut-path. However, in my case it only shows the relative path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had this need myself, here is my code:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/swagger.json',
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    oauth2RedirectUrl: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/swagger-ui/oauth2-redirect.html',
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl,
      HideTopbarPlugin
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  });
```

Just make sure the path to swagger.json is correct in the URL.